# SQL Server 2005 Varchar less than

Tags: sql-server-2005, int, varchar

I've googled this a bit and can't seem to find a good answer ...

I have a table with a `varchar(4)` column that contains 41 rows with `90` and 8 rows with `090`.

**Query 1** will return 9 rows, 8 rows with `90` and 1 with `090`

```
SELECT * 
FROM WorkArea..BSNOB_ServiceSalesParts_Testing
WHERE Source < '100'
ORDER BY Source DESC
```

**Query 2** will return all 49 rows, although the rows containing `090` are at the bottom of the results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM WorkArea..BSNOB_ServiceSalesParts_Testing
WHERE Source < 100
ORDER BY Source DESC
```

Can anyone explain to me why query 1 is missing data? And also why query 2 returns all data, but has `090` below `90` data? I figure this has something to do with conversion but I can't find any documentation explaining this.

Thank you.

Comment: When you alphabetize digits, what do you expect?  `0` comes before `9`, so a descending sort _should_ put `090` after `90`.  Are you sure that none of the fields contain spaces?  You can play with comparisons thusly: `select case when '090' > '90' then 'greater' else 'not' end`

Comment: The second query compares an integer (100) to a string ('090'), thus forcing a data type conversion. Converting the descriptions of numbers into integers causes the comparison to behave differently.  If one of the rows contained `Ten` as the `Source` you probably wouldn't like the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 2 displays the '090' data beneath the '90' data because that's what you're telling it to do in the ORDER BY aspect.

Remember, your SOURCE column is a VARCHAR. It's a string, despite being numbers, and as such will sort according to the rules of strings. Thus, it's looks at the first character for order, rather than to the numerical value.

If you want it to sort according to the numerical value which the string represents, then you'll need to cast the SOURCE column to an integer in the ORDER BY statement.

And as for why it returns all data, that's because you're comparing the numerical representation of a number to a number. SQL performs an implicit conversion within the where clause to deal with the boolean operator.

Now, your reported results for Query 1 are not what I'd expect. I'd expect for you to only get the 8 '090' rows, as those are the rows that would be less than the string '100' (and this is the result in SQL2012 as I just tested).

But to deal with why the results of the two queries are different, since you explicitly built the '100' as a string, it performs the comparison as a string and does not perform any conversions. 0 comes before 1 comes before 9 in string compares. It doesn't care that they are numbers, when the first character differentiates them enough for filtering.

Comment: Stephen, my apologies. I had an additional value that was '0900'. So Query 1 ACTUALLY returned '090' and '0900'. Your explanation makes perfect sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On your query 1, you are comparing 2 varchar. The rule for comparing varchar depends on the collation of your SQL server(default is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS). Check this: [[SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation sorting]](http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0409.1252.Latin1_General_CI_AS.html). The characters shown there are sorted from least to greatest. 
To check your collation, run the ff SQL(NOTE: change the DB name):

```
/* Identify Collation for a SQL Server database */
DECLARE @DatabaseName as SYSNAME
SET @DatabaseName = 'MYDB'  /* Replace Database Name Here....*/
SELECT 
 DB_NAME(DB_ID(@DatabaseName)) AS DatabaseName
,DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@DatabaseName, 'Collation') AS CollationUsedBySQLServerDatabase
GO
```

For your query 2, since you are comparing 1 number and 1 varchar, it will be forcing a data type conversion to number (as HABO has said in the comments).

To test some SQL comparison, use this SQL:

```
select 
case when 
('090'<'100') then 'TRUE'
else 'FALSE'
end
```